How do I parse a value from a data attribute in Cypress?
I have an input field:
<input type="range" id="amtRange" value="0" min="280" max="1400">

I want to get the value of the min attribute and see if it is less than another pre-existing value, i.e. the amount in the min attribute (280) should be less than the number in the amt variable.
I can get the value as a string as such:
cy.get('#amtRange').invoke('attr', 'min');

But cannot figure out how to pass it as an integer. I have tried the following:
const amt = 286;
let minAmt = cy.get('#amtRange').invoke('attr', 'min');
minAmt = parseInt(minAmt);
minAmt.should('be.lessThan', amt);

But this produces the error: TypeError: minAmt.should is not a function.
I have also tried:
const amt = 286;
cy.get('#amtRange').then(($amtInput) => {
    let minAmt = parseInt($amtInput.invoke('attr', 'min'));
    minAmt.should('be.lessThan', amt);
});

But this produces the error: $amtInput.invoke is not a function.
How can I achieve this?

Fundamentally, what you're trying doesn't make sense. You're missing a couple of pretty core concepts for writing tests in Cypress. Take the first snippet:
let minAmt = cy.get('#amtRange').invoke('attr', 'min');

.invoke doesn't return the value, it yields it, in the Cypress sense:

Cypress commands are asynchronous and get queued for execution at a later time. While commands are executed, their subjects are yielded from one command to the next. This is because a lot of helpful Cypress code runs between each command to ensure everything is in order.

Even if that did work, and then:
minAmt = parseInt(minAmt);

actually gave you a number, the next line:
minAmt.should('be.lessThan', amt);

doesn't follow. minAmt is a number, not a Cypress chain; it has no should method.
Similarly, the second snippet:
cy.get('#amtRange').then(($amtInput) => {
    let minAmt = parseInt($amtInput.invoke('attr', 'min'));
    minAmt.should('be.lessThan', amt);
});

gives you the actual jQuery element (as the $ prefix is intended to indicate - don't use this where you don't have an element!) That doesn't have an invoke method, though; it has the attr method. But then again even if you did the right thing:
let minAmt = parseInt($amtInput.attr('min'));

the result is a number, without a should method.
At this point you could use the vanilla "Mocha assertion":
expect(minAmt).to.be.lessThan(amt);
               // ^^^^^^^^^^^ same as should argument

However, that would impact the retry-ability. Ideally, you want to have a single chain of queries with an assertion at the end. For example, another way to write it would be:
cy.get('#amtRange').invoke('attr', 'min').should((minAmt) => {
  expect(parseInt(minAmt)).to.be.lessThan(amt);
});

I'd strongly recommend using TypeScript (which would tell you a Cypress.Chainable<string | undefined> isn't a string) and/or the ESLint plugin (which will tell you not to assign command return values) to highlight this kind of mistake much earlier.
